# Enforce unique key values in ExtJs 4 grids

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, datastore, gridpanel

I'm designing a grid in ExtJs 4 that will represent a Map data structure. I have a custom cell editor for the *key* column in the grid. I want to enforce the fact that the *key* must be unique among all keys. How do I go about doing this?

At the moment I'm trying to set up a special textfield editor with a custom validator that checks if the user-submitted *key* value is unique by comparing it to the dataStore's values. Unfortunately, this runs into the issue that the dataStore does not know what is the "current" record and so does not know which record to exclude when checking for duplicates.

^Confusing, right? That's why I think I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very good question, and I ended up doing pretty much exactly what you're doing. In order to handle current record so I can exclude it from the lookup I added something like that to the `vtype` validation function:

```
unique: function (val, field) {
  // If field has not been changed - don't care about anything else
  if (field.originalValue === undefined || val === field.originalValue) {
    // _trace('unique - original value has not changed'); 
    return true;
  }

  if (!field.isDirty()) {
    // _trace('unique - field is not dirty'); 
    return true;
  }

  // Check you store here...
},
uniqueText: 'Duplicate'
```

One more note - if you will try to use same validator in the dialogs (as oppose to grid roweditor) - you will need to add more checks because `originalValue` will not be properly set always (at least I had to do this in 4.0.7 in my application).

Comment: thanks for the answer! i haven't seen vtype before, and I looked into it. But I couldn't find out what `field` was. Can you explain what gets passed into the `unique: function(val,field)`, in context of Ext Js grids? Thanks so much!

Comment: `field` would be reference to the editor. When you use roweditor for grid it will actually create one Ext.form.field.Textfield for each column. And `val` obviously would be value that you need to check.

Comment: cool, thank you sha! I'll give this a try, and if no one posts another solution and it works then i'll accept it